# how to do the Check-Box enable disable in a Table-Column In JavaFX if i select one check-box i need to disable the remaining check-Boxes

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

how to do the Check-Box enable disable in a Table-Column In JavaFX  if i select one check-box i need to disable the remaining check-Boxes .

*if i select one check-box i need to disable the remaining check-Boxes in the table view*, in JavaFx.

```
colSelect.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean>, TableCell<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean>>()
{
   @Override
    public TableCell<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean> call(TableColumn<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean> param) {
        final TableCell<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<LogVoiceBroadCast, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Boolean value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);

                if (!empty || value != null) {

                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);

                    checkBox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                            if (!checkBox.isSelected()) {
                                LogVoiceBroadCast item = (LogVoiceBroadCast) getTableRow().getItem();
                                voiceFiles.add(item);

                            } else {
                                LogVoiceBroadCast item = (LogVoiceBroadCast) getTableRow().getItem();
                                voiceFiles.remove(item);

                            }

                        }
                    });

                    final HBox hbox = new HBox(checkBox);
                    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    hbox.setSpacing(12);
                    setGraphic(hbox);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: never-ever create controls in cell.updateItem - it's called often! Anyway, you need to implement logic in your data model, not in the view. Then the cells will be updated auto-magically

Comment: i need to disable in view level not in model level if any one check box is clicked then remaining will be disable,if it is unchecked all checkbox'e need to enable bro

Comment: no, you _must_ not implement logic in the view (and I'm __NOT__ your bro ;) - that's the responsibility of a model (name it view-model or whatever to distinguish from the underlying data): implement the logic somewhere outside and let the view react, that's the only clean path to go. Do or leave, it's you who will fail if you don't ;)

Comment: anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a for input events to trigger listen to changes in the `CheckBox` state. Instead add a listener to the `CheckBox.selected` property.

Furthermore you need to implement a way of restoring the `CheckBox` state, since different `TableCell`s may be used for the "checked row". Use some observable data structure to store this kind of information and use a listener to update the state of the `CheckBox`es:

```
TableView<Integer> table = new TableView<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    table.getItems().add(i);
}

TableColumn<Integer, Number> column = new TableColumn<>();
column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cd.getValue()));

// property to store the checked row item or null, if no row is checked
final ObjectProperty<Integer> selectedValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

TableColumn<Integer, Void> checkBoxColumn = new TableColumn<>();
checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Integer, Void>() {
    private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> selectionListener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            // use the row item as selected item, when checkbox is selected
            selectedValue.set((Integer) getTableRow().getItem());
        } else {
            // clear selected item, when checkbox is unselected
            selectedValue.set(null);
        }
    };

    private final ChangeListener<Integer> listener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            // update state without triggering the listener
            checkBox.selectedProperty().removeListener(selectionListener);
            if (newValue == null) {
                checkBox.setSelected(false);
                checkBox.setDisable(false);
            } else {
                boolean match = newValue.equals(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()));
                checkBox.setSelected(match);
                checkBox.setDisable(!match);
            }
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(selectionListener);
        }
    };

    {
        // listener should not prevent garbage collection of cell
        selectedValue.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(listener));

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(selectionListener);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(checkBox);
            listener.changed(null, null, selectedValue.get());
        }
    }

});

table.getColumns().addAll(column, checkBoxColumn);
```